# How to set treeview's childnode postback false on ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview, postback

I have a treeview and i want no postback on click any childnodes.And i will get selected childnode value.
I found a solution , when i set "node_.SelectAction = TreeNodeSelectAction.None;" i cant select any childnodes and no highlight on it.

Waiting your helps.Sorry about my en.

Aspx:

```
<asp:TreeView ID="TreeView1" runat="server"></asp:TreeView>
```

Cs:

```
TreeView1.Nodes.Clear();
TreeView1.TreeNodeExpanded += new TreeNodeEventHandler(TreeView1_TreeNodeExpanded);

DataTable dt = ImzaDll.Imza.KategorileriGetir(true);

foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
   TreeNode node_ = new TreeNode();
   node_.Text = row["ACIKLAMA"].ToString();
   node_.Value = row["KATEGORI"].ToString();
   TreeView1.Nodes.Add(node_);
}



void TreeView1_TreeNodeExpanded(object sender, TreeNodeEventArgs e)
{
   addChildNodes(e.Node);
}



private void addChildNodes(TreeNode node)
{
    DataTable dt = ImzaDll.Imza.KutuphaneBasliklariGetir(true, node.Value.ToString());

    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        TreeNode childNode = new TreeNode();
        childNode.Text = row["BASLIK"].ToString();
        childNode.Value = row["KUTUPHANE_ID"].ToString();
        childNode.ToolTip = row["BASLIK"].ToString() + " kütüphanesini ekle";
        childNode.Target = "_new";


        node.ChildNodes.Add(childNode);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set CSSClass of treeview child nodes
like

```
      <asp:TreeView LeafNodeStyle-CssClass="childnode" runat="server">....</asp:TreeView>
```

then using jquery you get get class and set return false like follow.

```
      $(".childnode").click(function(){
                 return false;
      })
```

...same way you can set RootNodeStyle-CssClass,  ParentNodeStyle-CssClass class and use jquery to set them...

Comment: Thanks it works for postback,how can i get selectedchildnode ?

Comment: what you actually want to achieve??you want to get selectedchildnode value in code behind??

Comment: Yes i want to get selectedchildnode value also I cant see like that "onchildnodeclick" on code behind.

Comment: you can set hidden field value in click event of childnode..like  $(".childnode").click(function(){ $("#HiddenfieldID").val(this.innerHTML) }), and then you can read that hidden field value from code behind.....make sense????

Comment: yea it works ! but a little problem is postback still active on expand nodes... When i press "+" (img button) postback is true, i tried set return false on jquery.now collapse doesnt work...

Comment: + button collapse/expand works handled by javascript (scriptresource.xsd/webresource) files that are loaded automatically when your treeview loaded..can you inspect using firebug etc that are those javascript included or not....

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9856/discussion-between-usman-and-serdar)

Answer (score 1):

```
TreeNode tn = new TreeNode();

tn.SelectAction = TreeNodeSelectAction.None; OR tn.SelectAction = TreeNodeSelectAction.Expand;
```

Both of these will not cause postback.

Answer (score 0):

you could remove the href of link('a') tag attribute to stop post back

```
$('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_tvHierarchyView table tr td>a').click(function () {  
      var treeViewData = window["<%=tvHierarchyView.ClientID%>" + "_Data"];        
      if (treeViewData.selectedNodeID.value != "") {      
            var selectedNode=document.getElementById(treeViewData.selectedNodeID.value);    
            var value = selectedNode.href.substring(selectedNode.href.indexOf(",") + 3, selectedNode.href.length - 2);                  
            var text = selectedNode.innerHTML;  
          alert("Text: " + text + "\r\n" + "Value: " + value);  
       } else {  
               alert("No node selected.")  
          }  
              $(this).removeAttr("href");

          ///  ...................... rest of your code

}); ///  End of click function    
}); /// End of document ready function
```

Here steps explanation:

1. Get the dev id which contains the tree table by Using inspect element:
2. Get details from the selected child node.
3. After taken the details of child node , remove the attribute "href" to avoid post back.
4. Do whatever functionality you what do with selected node details (eg pass selected value using ajax)